# Item Mismatch Exception in conways game of life

Tags: java

I'm working on a conway's game of life program for class.. the method below reads a specified input file, reads it into an int array, and returns that array..

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Proj5 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException   {
//the main method controls the flow of the program
    String filename = args[0];
    int[][] cells = readBoard(filename);

    for (int i = 0; i < cells.length; i++)  {
        for (int j = 0; j < cells[i].length; j++)   {
            System.out.print(cells[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

}

public static int[][] readBoard(String filename) throws IOException {
// This method reads the specified input file, reads it into an int[][] array, and returns that array.
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File(filename));
    int row = Integer.parseInt(inFile.nextLine());
    int col = Integer.parseInt(inFile.nextLine());

    int[][] cells = new int[row][col];

    inFile.nextLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)   {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)   {
            cells[i][j] = inFile.nextInt();
        }
        inFile.nextLine();
    }

    inFile.close();
    return cells;
}
```

And the text file that the scanner reads is formatted like below.. where the top line is the number of rows, second line is the number of columns, and the rest is the data that needs to be put into the array:

```
25
77
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000001110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000001110001110000000000000000000000000111110000000000000000000000
00000000000000111100000111100000000000000000001111100011111000000000000000000
00000000000000001110001110000000000000000000000000111110000000000000000000000
00000000000000000001110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000001110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000001110001110000000000000000000000000111110000000000000000000000
00000000000000111100000111100000000000000000001111100011111000000000000000000
00000000000000001110001110000000000000000000000000111110000000000000000000000
00000000000000000001110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

However, when i'm running my program.. i'm getting:

Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException: for input string:    "00000000000000000001110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(unknown source)

at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(unknown source)

at Proj5.readBoard(Proj5.java:30)

at Proj5.main(Proj5.java:8)

and i'm not entirely sure why or how to fix it...

Comment: I think the problem is that you're calling `inFile.nextInt()` which is finding a very long line of text (too long to fit into an int) - perhaps this should be inFile.nextChar()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `nextInt()` will attempt to convert each file row to a single integer.

An exception is thrown because the whole line, considered as a single number, wouldn't fit in an `int` value.

The way I'd proceed to fix this is to use one `readLine` call per row to consume an entire line of input. Then examine the character at a particular column of that row using that `charAt` method of `String`. If necessary, that can be efficiently converted to an `int` by subtracting the value of `'0'`.

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense. For some reason in my mind I was looking at it from the perspective of nextInt getting the next int in that row.. not the whole row being one long int.. This makes a lot of sense, thanks! :)